# Reference for Two-level Logistic Regression

Tags: self-study, logistic, references, sample-size

I am an undergraduate student  . In this level , we aren't taught `Multilevel Logistic Regression.` But  my project topic is Multilevel Logistic Regression and I am working with only two-level . What I know only  to use the `glmer()` function in `R` to estimate the fixed and random effect parameters . But I don't know , when to use which  `types of residuals` , though R has given the [reference](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/glm.summaries.html) `Davison, A. C. and Snell, E. J. (1991) Residuals and diagnostics` for the usages of each type , I didn't get the pdf of the reference .

Also I haven't any theoretical background of estimation procedure .

Would you please give me some online reference so that I can conduct my project issue `sample size determination in Multilevel Logistic Regression` fairly well ?

Thanks ! Regards .

Comment: Why do you want to use residuals from a logistic regression analysis, more or less a multilevel model? You hardly can do any of the diagnostic checking in either case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to [`residuals.merMod()`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lme4/docs/residuals.merMod). The default one for `glmer()`, deviance,  makes more sense. More examples are shown in this related question: [What do the residuals in a logistic regression mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1432/what-do-the-residuals-in-a-logistic-regression-mean)

> The default residual type varies between lmerMod and glmerMod objects:
>   they try to mimic residuals.lm and residuals.glm respectively. In
>   particular, the default type is "response", i.e. (observed-fitted) for
>   lmerMod objects vs. "**deviance**" for glmerMod objects. type="partial" is
>   not yet implemented for either type.