Bimodal residuals in logistic regression — what causes it, is it bad news, and what can be done?
I'm working with a large dataset with a binary response variable — here's a link to a simplified random sample of the data.
Fitting a binomial generalized linear model (GLM) to it, we see that the residuals are bimodally distributed based on the response variable:
dat <- read.csv("sampledat.csv", colClasses=c(rep("numeric",4),"factor"))
mod <- glm(response ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=dat, family="binomial")
plot(mod$residuals ~ mod$fitted.values, col=1+dat$response)


This is the case no matter which of my predictors ($x_1$; $x_2$; $x_3$ in the sample dataset) that I include, although the distance seems to shrink when I add more predictors.
The model diagnostic plots look accordingly messy as well:
plot(mod)


My questions are as follows:

Am I right in the interpretation that my residuals are bimodally distributed because there remains a lot of unexplained variation in my response variable?

Does this look like it affects the reliability of the model, or is it within the bounds of what you'd expect for a logistic regression? I've come across opinions online to the effect that these kinds of residual plots aren't meaningful for binomial responses, or at least shouldn't be interpreted in the same way as one would for a continuous response variable.

If this affects the reliability of my model, is there anything that can be done about it?



Your response is binary, so it can only be 0 or 1. Your fitted values are between 0 and 1, being the estimated probability for a given instance to be 1. So if an observation is 1, your fit will be too low, and you will have positive residuals $y-\hat{y}=1-\hat{y}$. If the observation is 0, your fit will be too high, and you will have a negative residual $y-\hat{y}=0-\hat{y}=-\hat{y}$. Except for situations like perfect fits, a binary response will pretty much always have a bimodal residual distribution. Standard diagnostic plots are not helpful here.

Thanks, but is this necessarily the case for the different types of residuals one can compute from a logistic regression? See here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/485734/410679
What you're describing sounds like the response residuals, and those are not what are used in the diagnostic plots.

I recommend checking out the dharma package for diagnostics that are most easily interpreted https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html#lm-and-glm

As answers to each of your questions:

Am I right in the interpretation that my residuals are bimodally distributed because there remains a lot of unexplained variation in my response variable?

No. This is because your outcome can literally only take values of the range $[0,1]$ and thus have no other way to vary in your plots.

Does this look like it affects the reliability of the model, or is it within the bounds of what you'd expect for a logistic regression?

Your classic residual plots are typically not as useful for logistic regression, so one cannot assess how reliable the estimates are here.

If this affects the reliability of my model, is there anything that can be done about it?

This is a bit of a vague question given a number of things can affect logistic models (perfect separation, lack of observed events per category, etc.). The solution will depend largely on how the model is fit and what the residuals offer in terms of clues for fixing the model.
As noted in the comments, using something like simulated residuals, such as those from the DHARMa package, offer a lot more utility in terms of assessing a model, so one should start there.

Thanks for the feedback. I've moved on to using DHARMa to assess my logistic models.
